# Selecting different strings resource file based on app preference (translation vs localization)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, localization

For the app I am working on I want to give the user the ability to select a different language than their phone is set to.

I have set everything up according to: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/multilingual-implementation-using-xamarin-forms/ and it works great for 'official' languages like French, English, Indonesian, etc. However, since the app is pretty much about any and all spoken (or signed) language, I also want to offer the option to select Klingon, Toki pona, Esperanto, Ido, etc.

When I try to set the language to Esperanto with
`CultureInfo language = new CultureInfo("eo");`

the app crashes with:
`Message (System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException)  "Culture name eo is not supported.\nParameter name: name"   string`

I have all the strings in resource files, I know exactly what the name of the file is for each language, and I don't need full localisation for these languages, so a way to force the use of 'AppResources.eo.resx' through code (after checking if the user has indeed set this preference) would also work.

Does anyone have ideas on how to do this? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious…

In case it matters, I have:
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.10.8 (build 0)
Mac OS X 10.16.0

Comment: On iOS, you must declare all supported languages in the Info.plist file for your project. In the Info.plist file, use the Source view to set an array for the CFBundleLocalizations key, and provide values that correspond to the Resx files.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, and I can select 'Esperanto' as the language, and then it crashes because "Culture name eo is not supported.\nParameter name: name"

Comment: Did you try to use `eo-001` ?